# Why may a single DNS server be responding two different things for the same query?

Tags: domain-name-system

I own a domain and configured through Digital Ocean DNS service --does this even matter?

I have a CNAME for `*.my.domain` to `ingress.my.domain`.

When I do a `dig` command, I get different results, e.g.:

```
➜  ~ dig abc.my.domain @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> abc.my.domain @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17257
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;abc.my.domain.              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
abc.my.domain.       21599   IN      CNAME   ingress.my.domain.
ingress.my.domain.    299     IN      A       <valid IP>

;; Query time: 198 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 03 08:48:15 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
```

Which works as intended. But immediately after I get:

```
➜  ~ dig abc.my.domain @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> abc.my.domain @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60455
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;abc.my.domain.              IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
my.domain.            449     IN      SOA     ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.my.domain. 1577916425 10800 3600 604800 1800

;; Query time: 116 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 03 08:48:16 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

Am I doing something wrong? Did I stumble with some propagation delays? How can I troubleshoot those kind of problems?

Comment: "How can I troubleshoot those kind of problems?" First rule: first check authoritative nameservers, before checking recursive ones and specifically open public ones.  Also do not obfuscate things when asking for help, and do not obfuscate badly.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek ok, that was harsh. I think that the problem was related to DNS propagation, so even if I hadn't obfuscate it, the problem is already irreproducible. Authoritative nameservers were already tried and they worked, sorry I omitted that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

8.8.8.8 (like many public resolvers) is not a single server but a large cluster.

Subsequent queries (even those from the same client)  are likely to be handled by different back-end servers and each server will likely have different cached records

You can usually observe that by either fluctuations in the TTL field (which for each server decreases steadily until it expires, but which will happen at a different time for each back end server) or completely different responses when a record  was recently updated and previous cached results still persist in some of those backend servers.

Google allows you to expire all cached results from its resolvers after you have updated your dns

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache

Answer (score 2):

`TTL` aka `Time To Live` can be an issue in this case, especially as this is set quite high for `abc.my.domain. 21599`. The listed value of `21559` is time in seconds.

TTL represents the time a DNS resolver is allowed to answer the request from a cache hit, instead of quering the full chain of DNS servers. Many resolvers honor the TTL, and it can be any resolver in the called chain who gives you an "old", but "correct" entry.

To avoid such issues during testing/setup it is helpful to use the `+trace` flag within dig. This enforces that the query is resolved from the root servers down to one authorative nameservers server (one server of the SOA record entries) for the zone.

Comment: "SOA servers"? You mean "authoritative nameservers"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The DNS records containing the authorative nameservers are called SOA which is the short form of `Start of Authority`.

Comment: "The DNS records containing the authorative nameservers are called SOA " No. First there is a single SOA, not plural. then the SOA encodes one nameserver, and it is not necessarily authoritative on the zone. See the SOA for `fr` for example.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying.